# lookup function doesn't work with unsorted list

Tags: google-sheets, lookup

Why does this work, and looks up values correctly

[image]

but once i change the order of values, it produces incorrect values?

[image]

Answer (score 37, accepted):

If you read the notes on the LOOKUP function, it says:

> The LOOKUP function will only work properly if data in search_range or search_result_array is sorted. Use VLOOKUP, HLOOKUP, or other related functions if data is not sorted.

Change your formula to use VLOOKUP as follows:

```
=VLOOKUP(D3, A1:B6, 2, FALSE)
```

Syntax:

> VLOOKUP(search_key, range, index, [is_sorted])
>
> search_key - The value to search for. For example, 42, "Cats", or I24.
>
> range - The range to consider for the search. The first column in the range is searched for the key specified in search_key.
>
> index - The column index of the value to be returned, where the first column in range is numbered 1.
>
> is_sorted - [OPTIONAL - TRUE by default] - Indicates whether the column to be searched (the first column of the specified range) is sorted.

Comment: Based on the documentation of `IFERROR`, if you keep your lookup table in a second page of the sheet, you can can have a default value for failed lookups like: `=IF(NOT(ISNA(VLOOKUP(B2,'<sheet_name>'!A:B,2, FALSE))), VLOOKUP(B2,'<sheet_name>'!A:B,2, FALSE), "<default>")`, where column A is keys, and B is values, unsorted in sheet "<sheet_name>".

Comment: VLOOKUP is not a substitute for LOOKUP because it requires the lookup value to be in the 1st column.

Comment: @ThorSummoner Maybe you meant to write this (since you mentioned `IFERROR`) but you can just do `=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(B2,'<sheet_name'!A:B,2, FALSE), "<default">)`

Comment: @Nick `VLOOKUP` requires the lookup value to be in the first column of the *range* specified. The only situation it wouldn't substitute for `LOOKUP` is when the column of the desired result is left of the column of the lookup value.

Comment: @ChuckBatson Yeah, that's what I said.

Comment: Found the solution for doing an unsorted lookup where the result range is before the search range.

INDEX(result_range,MATCH(search_key,search_range,0))

Source: https://yagisanatode.com/2017/11/27/vlookup-left-in-google-sheets-with-index-and-match/

Comment: @flyingsolow Thank! You should add it as an answer so it is seen more easily, because this fixes a really glaring inadequacy of LOOKUP.

Comment: @flyingsolow that should be the answer, solved my problem